# How can I pass a sequence as a parameter in Perl 6?

Tags: seq, raku

In Perl 6, I can iterate a literal sequence:

```
.say for 0 ... 3;
```

I can bind to a scalar and iterate that:

```
my $s := 0 ... 3;
.say for $s;
```

But I can't bind to a scalar, pass it as an argument, and then iterate that:

```
my $t := 0 ... 3;
show( $t );

sub show ( $seq ) { .say for $seq }
```

The subroutine gets a single element of type [Seq](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq), but it doesn't iterate it.

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
(0 1 2 3)
```

Does something in the process of preparing the parameter iterate through everything already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## A value held in a [Scalar](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar) container is *not* automatically iterated

While both `$s` and `$seq` are [scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29) (aka "variables"), `$s` is bound directly to a Seq value whereas your `$seq` is bound to an intermediary [Scalar](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar) (note uppercase `S`) "container" that in turn contains the Seq. A value held in a Scalar container is *not* automatically iterated when used with features like `for`.

---

In more detail:

```
my $s := 0 ... 3;
.say for $s;
```

Because the `my` variable declaration uses the direct binding operator [`:=`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$COLON$EQUALS_SIGN) for initialization, `$s` is *directly* bound to the single Seq value `0 ... 3`.

This means the `for` statement sees a single Seq value, determines that it does the Iterable role, and flattens (iterates) it.

Now consider this:

```
my $s := 0 ... 3;
my $container = $s;
.say for $container;
```

Because the second `my` declaration uses the assignment operator [`=`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$EQUALS_SIGN) for initialization, the new variable `$container` is first bound to a new Scalar container which then "contains" whatever gets assigned.

In keeping with the language wide [Slurpy Conventions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#Slurpy_Conventions) (in particular: "An Iterable inside a Scalar container does not count"), a `for` statement does not iterate a value held in a Scalar container, so the `.say for $container` line only does one `say`.

A similar situation applies for your original `show` routine because variable parameter declarations are (semantically) containers by default.

One option is to instead add an `is raw` trait to your `$seq` parameter:

```
sub show ( $seq is raw ) { .say for $seq }
```

This prevents the usual automatic binding of `$seq` to a Scalar container (that in turn would contain the Seq value) as part of the call to `show`.

Another option is to let `$seq` be bound to a Scalar container but explicitly flatten (iterate) the `$seq` variable in the body of the `show` routine using a prefix `|`:

```
sub show ( $seq ) { .say for |$seq }
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the `is raw` parameter trait suggested by raiph, you can also use a sigil-less variable as the parameter, which doesn't introduce a `Scalar` container:

```
sub show (\seq) { .say for seq }
```

(You can also use this form for normal variables, as in `my \a = 5; say a;`, but note that they are single-assignment only.)

A variation of this is the `+` form, which passes on the raw argument if it is an `Iterable` (like a `List` or `Seq`), but when a non-iterable argument is passed it promotes it to a `List` of one element, so that the body of the function can rely on always getting an `Iterable`:

```
sub show (+seq) { .say for seq }
```

(This is what most of the built-in list processing routines like `grep` and `zip` use.)

Of course if you prefer to use a `$` parameter that introduces a `Scalar` container, you can just "decontainerize" it again before iterating over it, by calling the `.list` method on it:

```
sub show ($seq) { .say for $seq.list }  # explicit

sub show ($seq) { .say for @$seq }      # short-hand syntax
```

(Update: Eh, `.list` actually turns the `Seq` into a `List`, i.e. it won't be memory-efficient in case of a large `Seq`. Using `|$seq` like you already discovered in your own answer, doesn't have this problem.)

Comment: Thanks! But yeah, I'm thinking about infinite lazy sequences. :)

Comment: just to mention the decont op <>  viz. https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3C%3E

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Parameter) ...

```
sub foo($bar) { say $bar }     # $bar is a parameter 
foo(42);                       # 42 is an argument
```

Also [here](https://docs.raku.org/type/Parameter#___top) ...

```
Sigil Binds to  Default behavior
$   Scalar      Generate new Scalar, use instead of Scalar in argument, if any
@   Positional  Bind directly to the argument
@   PositionalBindFailover  If binding failed, call argument's .cache method, bind to result
%   Associative Bind directly to the argument
&   Callable    Bind directly to the argument
\   (anything)  Bind directly to the argument, keep existing Scalar, if any
```

With Sigil $ the caller Scalar container is distinct from the callee Scalar container and the call does an implicit assignment. [Nevertheless '\' and 'is raw' are ways to disable this and to force binding if that is what you prefer.]

I gather that the intent is to have containers be local to blocks by default to help memory separation and parallelization. All other Sigils bind directly - but they are amenable to parallelization in other ways.

So the Sigil $ carries implications both for Iterability and for Separation.